# Can Django Templates have Dynamic model content under the same "Template.html" name?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-views

I have a main page with images of books that are href links in a template {% for %} statement that generates them.  It roughly looks like this:

```
{% for book in books %}
<a href="/single_book/">
  <img src="{{book.image}}">
</a>
```

I would like for once the image gets clicked on to redirect to a dynamically generated page about the book that uses info from the model to generate the content such as the book title, author, year published, and description.  Is there a way to do this using an html file like "single_book.html" and it will show unique content when each book is clicked?

I looked up some URL patterns such as:

```
url(r'^single_book/(\w+)/$', single_book),
```

But does that mean each saved html file has to be saved for each book, so book one is: "single_book/book1.html" and book two is "single_book/book2.html" ?  I would like to just have one one html template file of "single_book.html" that does it for each book.

If there is a way to do this, what would also be the view.py code, etc...?  I am running Django 1.6 and Python 2.7.  Using a MySQL DB.  I'm just practicing using the "manage.py runserver" for the time being.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create single html file for the details of a particular book:

book_detail.html

```
{{book.title}}
{{book.author}}
{{book.description}}
```

You just need to pass the instance of a book to the template `book_detail.html` which is requested by the user:

The url:

```
url(r'^single_book/(\d+)/$', single_book),
```

The View:

```
def single_book(request, pk):
    book = Book.objects.get(pk=pk)
    ctx = {'book': book}
    return render_to_response('book_detail.html', RequestContext(request, ctx))
```

Comment: thank you, still couldn't figure it out. i'm going to keep working at it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's how templates are supposed to be used. If you read [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) about Django's Class Based Views (specifically, DetailView) you can get a rough outline of what you should do:

```
# views.py, using the generic CBV DetailView
class SingleBookView(DetailView):
    object = Book

singlebook = SingleBookView.as_view()

# url.py change slightly so you can use named urls in templates
url(r'^single_book/(?P<pk>\w+)/$', singlebook, name='singlebook')
```

Then the template can be the same single_book.html for every book, since the book object will be automatically detected by the view using the pk param from your url

```
<p>{{ object.title }}</p>
```

Plus, you can now use named urls:

```
{% for book in books %}
    {# see how your original loop changes with named urls #}
    <a href="{% url singlebook book.pk %}">
        <img src="{{book.image}}">
    </a>
```

Comment: thank you both for your help. i still can't figure it out. I think that i need to go back to some Django basics, and build up to this concept, so that's probably what I'll end up doing.

Comment: So, i got it working. Thank you.  I had to look at the Django Tutorial docs, then compared to what you guys offered for advice, and got it to work.  I had the file to be used in the URLConf instead of having it in the View with the URL only providing the URL structure. So cool guys, thanks again for your help.